# MySQL sorting numbers with prefix

Tags: mysql

I have a field called "mark" in database which contains following data:

```
P-9
R-12
R-10
P-10
P-11
R-11
R-9
R-8
P-12
P-8
...
```

The prefix can be upto 4 characters before digit.

Expected output:

```
P-8
P-9
P-10
P-11
P-12
R-8
R-9
R-10
R-11
R-12
....
```

So far i have:

```
ORDER BY CAST(mark AS UNSIGNED), mark ASC
```

This seems to **almost** work correctly, but it does not sort correctly numbers which are lower than 10.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to store the prefix separately from the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:** Using <kbd>[Right & Left](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_right.asp)</kbd> Method you can sort in required way

```
ORDER BY LEFT(Marks,1),CAST(RIGHT(Marks,len(Marks)-2) AS INT)
```

Comment: Hi i've tried it, but it does not sort prefix in right order.

Comment: Your updated answer almost works, but numbers < 10 will be placed at the end. Example: P-23 > P-24 > P-8 > P-9

Comment: Thank you, i changed INT to UNSIGNED, and on my case it works.

"ORDER BY LEFT(mark,1), CAST(RIGHT(mark,length(mark)-2) AS UNSIGNED)"

Comment: I think the condition `The prefix can be upto 4 characters before digit.` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
order by substring(mark,1,locate('-',mark)+1), cast(substring(mark,locate('-',mark)+1) as unsigned) asc
```

Comment: Same as above, it puts numbers <10 at the end.

Comment: @Pandicted Try Now.

Answer (score 0):

My variant with `SUBSTRING(code,LOCATE('-',code)+1)`

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
  code varchar(10)
);

INSERT Test VALUES
('PPP-9'),
('RR-12'),
('RRRR-10'),
('P-10'),
('P-11'),
('R-11'),
('R-9'),
('R-8'),
('P-12'),
('P-8');

SELECT
  *,
  CAST(SUBSTRING(code,LOCATE('-',code)+1) AS UNSIGNED) NUM,
  LEFT(code,LOCATE('-',code)-1) PREFIX
FROM Test
ORDER BY
  CAST(SUBSTRING(code,LOCATE('-',code)+1) AS UNSIGNED),
  LEFT(code,LOCATE('-',code)-1)
```

Or

```
...
ORDER BY
  LEFT(code,LOCATE('-',code)-1),
  CAST(SUBSTRING(code,LOCATE('-',code)+1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: I added `LEFT(code,LOCATE('-',code)-1)`. Try to check it again.

Comment: Same issue, seems to sort by the number only. Example: P-8, R-8, P-9, R-9

Comment: Try to change order in `ORDER BY` => `ORDER BY LEFT(code,LOCATE('-',code)-1),  CAST(SUBSTRING(code,LOCATE('-',code)+1) AS UNSIGNED)`